# How to use a custom ValidatorUpdateDisplay function when the controls / validators are loaded on postback in an UpdatePanel the first time?

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms, updatepanel, postback

In ASP.NET when using validation controls (i.e. `RequiredFieldValidator`) the client sided framework will execute the JS function `Page_ClientValidate`. This function will validate all controls on the page (of the given `ValidationGroup`) and call the JS function `ValidatorUpdateDisplay` with a parameter of the DOM element of the `span` tag of the validator control.

`ValidatorUpdateDisplay` toggles the visibility of the `span` tag depending on the result of the validation.

In my web application I've overridden the `ValidatorUpdateDisplay` JS function to provide more functionality on the validation scenario (i.e. red borders around the controls, showing popover on the first failed control and scrolling to it).

Now this works very well until my controls (incl. submit button) are shown the first time after a postback in an UpdatePanel.

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upTest" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="bShow" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" Text="SHOW" OnClick="bShow_Click" />
        <asp:Panel ID="pContent" runat="server" Visible="false">
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbTest" runat="server" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvTest" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbTest" Text="Not valid" />
            <asp:Button ID="bTest" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" Text="TEST" />
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ValidatorUpdateDisplay(val) {
        debugger; // this will not be reached
    }
</script>

protected void bShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.pContent.Visible = true;
}
```

After initial load press `bShow` to display `pContent`.
Now, if you leave `tbTest.Text` empty and press on `bTest` it should enter the overridden `ValidatorUpdateDisplay` function, however it enters the function of the framework and displays "Not valid" from `rfvTest`.

If you change `pContent.Visible` to `true` and press `bTest` after initial load the desired effect will happen: It will enter the custom `ValidatorUpdateDisplay` function and not display "Not valid".

If you move the button `bTest` out of the `UpdatePanel` the problem persists.

How can I make it work inside an `UpdatePanel`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET uses a lazy loading approach to insert the `ValidatorUpdateDisplay` function when it needs it the first time, hence in my example it will load the function after the postback of the `UpdatePanel`.

This will override my own implementation of the `ValidatorUpdateDisplay` function, because it's inserting the function at the end of the page.

There is a dirty workaround, I just inserted an empty `CustomValidator` on initial load that is always valid:

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" />
```

I wish there was a cleaner solution.