# How to make the RangeValidator on an input of type "number" work in all localizations?

Tags: asp.net, html, webforms, rangevalidator

The `RangeValidator` will fetch the `value` of the `input` and validate it with regex. Part of the regex is the localized decimal character.

So, in the German culture the `RangeValidator` will fail if I enter `100.00`, however it will accept `100,00`, because `,` is the decimal character of the German culture.

On the new `input[type=number]` (`asp:TextBox` with `TextMode="Number"`) of HTML5, I can enter `100,00` or `100.00` (with the `step`attribute set to "0.01" and it will always hold the value `100.00`. This will cause the `RangeValidator` to fail all the time in the German culture.

Changing the location to `en-US` would solve the problem, but I need the application in the users locale.

Can I, somehow, tell the `RangeValidator` to always use `.` as decimal character or are there any better ways to handle this situation?

Comment: Tried it but cannot reproduce the problem (Dutch uiCulture). The `input[type=number]` will only hold integers and will color red when either a ',' or a '.' is entered. But the `RangeValidator` works as it should. `<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" type="number"></asp:TextBox><asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RangeValidator" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" MinimumValue="2" MaximumValue="20" Type="integer"></asp:RangeValidator>`

Comment: @VDWWD Sry, forgot to mention. Set the `step` attribute of the input to "0.01" to enable it to enter floated values. Then the problem will occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is dirty but works:

I've overridden the `ValidatorValidate` function of the framework:

```
function ValidatorValidate(val, validationGroup, event) {
    // new code: 
    if (typeof (val.customized) == "undefined") {
        var data = $(val).data();
        for (var key in data) {
            val[key] = data[key];
        }
        val.customized = true;
    }

    // this code was copied from the framework:
    val.isvalid = true;
    if ((typeof (val.enabled) == "undefined" || val.enabled != false) && IsValidationGroupMatch(val, validationGroup)) {
        if (typeof (val.evaluationfunction) == "function") {
            val.isvalid = val.evaluationfunction(val);
            if (!val.isvalid && Page_InvalidControlToBeFocused == null &&
                    typeof (val.focusOnError) == "string" && val.focusOnError == "t") {
                ValidatorSetFocus(val, event);
            }
        }
    }
    ValidatorUpdateDisplay(val);
}
```

And now I can force specific JS variables on the validator by using data attributes. To force the `RangeValidator` to use the `en-US` locale, I simply force it to set `decimalchar` to `.` and `digits` to `2` from the ASPX markup:

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="rv" runat="server" Data-DecimalChar="." Data-Digits="2" MinimumValue="-100" MaximumValue="100" ControlToValidate="tb" Type="Currency" />
```

But, this is just dirty, it's not? ...

**Please [be aware of problems with UpdatePanels when overriding JS functions that involve the client validation mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39273000/how-to-use-a-custom-validatorupdatedisplay-function-when-the-controls-validato), like this one.**

What I'm really confused about is the fact this works, even when I'm only modifying the client side script. The server sided validation accepts the value from the English culture. This is really strange.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the specific number format settings on `Page_PreInit` and change the decimal separator without changing the whole UI language.

```
    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CultureInfo newCulture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
        NumberFormatInfo numberFormat = (NumberFormatInfo)newCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
        numberFormat.NumberDecimalDigits = 2;
        numberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
        newCulture.NumberFormat = numberFormat;
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
    }
```

Comment: I know I can do that, but this is not a good step, because on other parts of the website I just want to display the number in a Label localized. Replacing the `NumberDecimalSeparator` of the current culture would cause all my numbers to display with a `.` as decimal separator.

Comment: It would be per page, not the entire project. But the numeric separator of the new input uses the browser language localization, not the one from the website so it seems. So it is probably very difficult to get them to work together. I was looking for an override of the validation function for the stepper, but it's probably in the browser engine so that won't work either.

Comment: "But the numeric separator of the new input uses the browser language localization" - My browser is using the German locale and it still uses the dot. It would be a terrible mess, if it would be different. (https://jsfiddle.net/0abryffk/1/ - Pressing the button will return "1.22" in my German localized Google Chrome / Firefox) --- "It would be per page, not the entire project." - I know that, but on the same page I display other values where I need the correct localized decimal separator.